# Django DRY List iteration

Tags: django, list, iteration, dry

As someone who is just starting to use Django in my scarce time, I appreciate in advance your time in helping me learn how to make my code cleaner and correct.

I have two lists comprised of two querysets as follows:

```
company_list = [Company_stats.objects.filter(period__exact=P, company_name__in=master_names)]
industry_list = [Industry_stats.objects.filter(period__exact=P, industry_name__in=master_names)]
```

I iterate through both lists in my template to create a small table.

```
{%for c in company_list%}
    {%for z in c %}
         {{ z.company_name }}                  
         {{ z.nxt_m_ret_est }} 
         {{ z.nxt_m_ret_rat }} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{%for c in industry_list%}
    {%for z in c %} 
         {{ z.industry_name }}                  
         {{ z.nxt_m_ret_est }} 
         {{ z.nxt_m_ret_rat }}  
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works fine, however, since I am using the same code except for z.industry_name vs. z.company_name I was wondering whether you could help me figure out a better way to do this.

I have tried combining the lists into one list with both querysets in it and that works except for the obvious issue that I don't know how to tell it to retrieve z.company_name or z.industry_name depending on the queryset where the data is coming from, because everything became part of the same list.

Comment: You are aware that you're creating a list with exactly one element in your code snippet above? ``foo = [bar]`` creates a list with one element. Did you mean to write ``foo = list(bar)`` or ``foo = bar``? that will save you the outer loop in both statements

Comment: Jonas, thank you for your response. The first loop returns [[<Company_stats: AkzoNobel>, <Company_stats: Aegon>, <Company_stats: Aalberts>]] while the second loop is the one that actually retrieves the values. There might be a better way to do it and I more than welcome the suggestion :) but as it stands I don't know how to retrieve all the data with just one loop.

Comment: I suggested it already, try ``company_list = list(Company_stats.objects[…])``, without the ``[]`` and a ``list()`` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry I didn't get it the first time. But in your opinion I do need to loop both lists, there is no way to loop over one list and retrieve different fields from different querysets (I apologize again for my ignorance  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've changed the field to `name` on both models you can put both querysets into the same list and then iterate over that.

```
master_list = [model.objects.filter(period__exact=P, name__in=master_names) for model in (Company_stats, Industry_stats)]
```

...

```
{% for l in master_list %}
    {% for i in l %}
         {{ i.name }}                  
         {{ i.nxt_m_ret_est }} 
         {{ i.nxt_m_ret_rat }} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ignacio. I can't change the name as suggested as per my answer to jimhark.

Comment: Then add a property `name` that returns the proper value, and modify the Python code to generate both querysets explicitly in the same sequence.

Comment: Ignacio, thank you very much again for your help. Since I just started using Django, I am afraid that I don't know how to do what you suggest. I would really appreciate your guidance in helping me learn that.

Comment: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/aug/18/django-tips-using-properties-models-and-managers/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the code be more generic, it would help to make your names more generic. Would it be possible for you to change `industry_name` and `company_name` to just `name` throughout your system?

Comment: jimjar, thank you for your response. I can't do that, because the model that contains the company_name field also has an industry_name field. I can't use Foreign Keys for those because they don't work with the charting app I am using.